# What does iid with zero mean +- 1 entries imply?

Tags: matrices, statistics

I'm looking at a statement in a paper and do not understand what it means:

It says : let X be a matrix with i.i.d zero mean with +- 1 entries.

What does this matrix look like and what are reasons for having such a matrix?

Paper reference Theorem 14 on page 7:

[Sarlos Paper](http://labs.yahoo.com/files/rp-focs.pdf)

Comment: Can yoiu reference the paper and give a little more detail, such as a complete sentence from the paper?  so we can get the details?

Comment: Added reference

Answer (score 2):

It means that the entries of the matrix are random variables, independent and identically distributed, with a sample space of $\{-1, 1\}$, chosen with equal probability.

Comment: How does zero mean argument come in?

Comment: Suppose I have a discrete random variable that can take two values, $a$, with probability $p_a$, and $b$, with probability $p_b = 1-p_a$. The expected value is $E[X] = ap_a+bp_b = ap_a+b(1-p_a) = (a-b)p_a+b$. If $p_a = p_b$, that is equal probability, then $E[X] = \frac{a+b}{2}$. Now let $a = -b$. You'll see that zero-mean occurs iff $p_a = p_b$.